# Why is my onSelected constantly redirecting my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-plugins, dropdown

I am using `ddslick` as my dropdown plugin. `onSelected` my page keeps redirecting. Why is that happening?

```
$('#myDropdown').append(
    `<option value="${d.data.runId}" ${selected} data-description="by: ${user_name} <br> ${local_Datetime}" data-imagesrc="${site_logo}">
    ${d.data.runId}
    </option>`);
});

$("#enter_audit").on("keyup", function() {
  $('.dd-options').show();
  let value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $(".dd-options li").filter(function() {
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
  });
});

$('#myDropdown').ddslick({
  width:327, height:350, imagePosition:"right",
  selectText: "Select an audit",
  onSelected: function(e){
    window.location = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + "?run_id=" + e.selectedData.value;
    get_run(e.selectedData.value);
  }   
});
```

Why is this happening?

ddslick: http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Well... When you over ride the ```window.location``` value, some form of redirection of some sort is going to happen...

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara, It doesnt stop redirecting. I only need it to redirect once to the selected value

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V How am I overriding?

Comment: You literally have a line that executes... ```window.location = ...```... Don't take this as me being mean, but maybe you should go through more documentation? An example being [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/). I mean what are you actually trying to do there?

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V, I dont think its mean but I am confused... on option select I just want to go the `window.location` I set up. I am fairly new to javascript so this is confusing for me. When I add a button and do this: `onSelected: function(e){
          $('#get-run-button').on('click', function() {
            window.location = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + "?audit_run_id=" + e.selectedData.value;
            get_run(e.selectedData.value);
            $('#get-run-button').removeClass('pulse-primary');
          });
        }   
    });` It works perfectly!

Comment: Okay, fair enough, but the window object is a global object, some properties, if overridden can screw things up badly... With the location property, if you assign a value to that property, it will redirect you, you don't even need to be on a web-page.. If you open a new tab, press f12 and enter ```window.location = 'https://www.youtube.com/';```, you'll end up on YouTube...

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V I get it now. Thanks!